# How can you get access to the firing dom node inside a dojo.xhrPost load?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have an html fragment like the following:

```
<li>
    <img src="/jsafe/gallery/item/83/thumb" />
    <span class="tools">
        <a href="/jsafe/gallery/item/83/rotate/left">
            <img src="/jsafe/img/rotate_left_small.png" alt="Rotate Left"/>
        </a>

        <a href="/jsafe/gallery/item/83/rotate/right">
            <img src="/jsafe/img/rotate_right_small.png" alt="Rotate Right"/>
        </a>
    </span>
</li>
```

I have a dojo fragment like the following:

```
dojo.query(".tools a:nth-child(1)").forEach(function(node,index,arr){
    dojo.connect(node, "onclick", null, function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        dojo.xhrPost({
            url: dojo.attr(e.currentTarget, "href"),
            handleAs: "json",
            load: function(data) {
                //TODO
            }
            },
            error: function(error) {
                var u = "";
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Inside the load function how can I get to the e.currentTarget dom node? I know load is a separate callback function but I need to get to that dom node to do more manipulation.

Comment: If you refer to "e" in any of your functions defined within the handler function, you automatically create a closure which closes over the variable "e".  However, beware of using too many closures, as it makes your code difficult to debug and it is very easy to introduce mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try just referring to `e.currentTarget` from within the `load` function? :)

Since your `load` function is defined within the event handler function which has access to `e`, you still have access to it.

Perhaps the explanation here will help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures